# Repeating ReactDOM.render based on array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a simple React app that contains an array of data displayed in a container created within React:

```
var products = [
{ name: 'product 1'},
{ name: 'product 2' },
{ name: 'product 3' },
{ name: 'product 4' }
];

var Status = React.createClass({

render: function () {

    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function (item) {
        return (
            <h2 key={item.name}>
               {item.name}
            </h2>
        );
    });
    return (           
        <div className="ContainerName">
        {listItems}                                              
        </div>     
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Status items={products} />,
document.getElementById('statusContainer'));
```

The issue I have is that I want the "ContainerName" div (or Status var) to render according to the number of items in the array (4 times, but currently it only renders once).

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Status items={products} />,
document.getElementById('statusContainer'), products.length);
```

Is ReactDom only meant to be used once? Or is there there a way I can reuse the component according to the array length? Or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: what you want to achieve? why you want to use ReactDOM.render 4 times any specific reason?

Comment: @MayankShukla I just want the div to render according to the number of items in the array, it doesn't have to be specifically 4 times - if the array had 10 items I'd therefore like the div to render 10 times.

Comment: The render function must return a single root element with any number of children. Therefore you could wrap your `h2` in a `div.ContainerName` and rename the one in the return to something like `div.statusContainerRoot`.

Comment: why would you even want it to render the same number of times as the array length. How will it help. Not a good thing to do

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Well I guess thats why I asked the question on here - so I could understand the right way to do it! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render function must return a single root element with any number of children. This would work:

```
var products = [
  { name: 'product 1'},
  { name: 'product 2' },
  { name: 'product 3' },
  { name: 'product 4' }
];

var Status = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var listItems = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="ContainerName" key={item.name}>
          <h2>{item.name}</h2>
        </div>
       );
    });

    return <div className="statusComponentRoot">{listItems}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Status items={products} />,
  document.getElementById('statusContainer')
);
```

Comment: Ahhh yep that makes sense. Yeah I thought it would be simple to just duplicate the render enough times, but I guess not! Cheers for the help, thats awesome